# How to prevent unknown page hits on Mautic on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mautic

I have a Mautic instance deployed on Google Cloud Platform. The installation was done with Bitnami installer.

Everything works great, except I'm getting hundreds of page hits even though I haven't implemented a single tag.

Looking at the consequent anonymous contacts created, the page hits come from multiple computers whose the IP addresses are from China. They also seem to be aiming to get inside my phpMyAdmin.

These access contribute to falsely increasing the page view statistics, and virtually makes the awesome software useless.

Is there any way to prevent them to make page hits, resulting in false stats?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewall-rules-logging) to block these IPS and drop their traffic, if you have them, and yo can as well use [Cloud Armor Security](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies) this will let you enable IP blacklist/whitelist for your HTTP(S) Load Balancing